# Get json value on any php page

Tags: php, javascript, json

I am creating json object but can't access its value in php.I am trying to access json object in php and assign that object to php variable.My js code is

```
var arr= [];
 var data={ "tab" : 'system' };
jObjArr = arr.push(data);
 var JSONstr = JSON.stringify(jObjArr);
```

what i am missing ?

I try to get tab value on that page in php.

Comment: How are you sending the JSON to PHP, via AJAX? If so, show us that code.

Comment: this is js code. It starts after php is done executing. PHP cannot read this

Comment: How you implementing it means weather json object is on same page or different,if diff then access that link to `PHP` page and call that variable and access its value....

Comment: I try to print in php

Comment: it will be no matter whether they are on same page or different but i want to grab that js value in php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to pass simple object rather than sending an array:

```
    function send_me() {
        //var arr = [];
        var data = { "tab": 'system' };
        //jObjArr = arr.push(data);
        //var JSONstr = JSON.stringify(data);
        $.ajax({
            url: "a_blank.php",
            type:"post",
            data: data,
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response);
            }
        });
    }
```

On php page side simply get as:

```
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST")
     {
      print_r($_POST['tab']);
       die();
     }
```